# Selected block only need to be fix at top while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

Keep only the selected `li`elements of the list  fixed to the top.

```js
jQuery(".list-outer ul li").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("li-active");
});
```

```css
.li-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-outer">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Content blk1
    </li>
    <li>
      Content blk2
    </li>
    <li>
      Content blk3
    </li>
    <li>
      Content blk4
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Example:** If selected  second and fourth `li` elements, when scroll happens keep them fixed on top.

Comment: I have really no idea what you are asking for!

Comment: @eisbehr same as you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the selected elements visible  while you scroll, you can archive this with CSS by adding an attribute to the `list`:

```
.li-active {
    background: red;
    position:fixed;
}
```

---

For a better looking I would recomend you to create 2 lists, the normal one and another one with selected elements.

```
<ul class="list-outer">
    <li>
      Content blk1
    </li>
    <li>
      Content blk2
    </li>
    <li>
      Content blk3
    </li>
    <li>
      Content blk4
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="selected-list"></ul>
```

When you select one just move to the selected list:

```
$(".list-outer ul li").click(function() {
  $(this).detach().appendTo(".selected-list");
});
```

By this way you will have only the selected list fixed in you page :

```
.selected-list{
    position:fixed;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** 
To return it back to the previous list:

```
$(".selected-list li").on('click',function() {
  $(this).detach().appendTo(".list-outer");
});
```

Comment: thank you. This working correctly. one more help please that is how can i place it back to original list( .list-outer ) when i clicked on selected-list li

Comment: This way it worked. bcz it is dynamically added element.                jQuery('.selected-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
      jQuery(this).detach().appendTo(".list-outer");
});                                                                                                                                                                                           Your answer led me to the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ CristianS9 One more help please...How can i limit the number of items in .selected-list. That is only two items should add to selected-list from list-outer. And show a message if more than two selected.

Comment: Add a `var selected = 0;` And then just add or substract it in each function, also in add function add an `if(selected<2)`

Comment: Can you please check this. First round working is correct. Then alert is showing when it return back to the previous list. Can you help me to solve this problem   ` var count=0;
    jQuery(".main-list li").click(function () {
        if(count < 2){                                     
           jQuery(this).detach().appendTo(".selected-list");        count++;
        } else {  alert("only two items can select"); }
    });
jQuery('.selected-list').on('click', 'li', function () { 
   jQuery(this).detach().appendTo(".main-list");                                                    });  `

Comment: You also need `count--;` when and element is out of the list